# Error when using LDAP Views within Rules

Tags: views, rules, authentication-authorization

My objective is to pick a user from an ldap and then create his drupal account.

In order to do this,

1) a user picks a name (dn) from an LDAP server using the [LDAP Entry Reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/ldap_entry_reference) module (which offers autocomplete search)

2) after the user has completed his input, I use a Rule to create the drupal account :
 - dn enables me to search the LDAP with a "View Loop" and get the email
 - with the name and the email, the rules can create the drupal account.

I use [LDAP Query](https://www.drupal.org/node/1302080) and LDAP Views to build the view.

The problem is that the View Loop returns empty results although the views results are correct if I use the views from UI.

I have tested the view with no parameter, no filter, simple LDAP Query, minimalistic ldap (3 users in the LDAP).
My connection to the LDAP is OK : new users can log in with LDAP before drupal account creation : all this is OK.

Do you know of such an error using LDAP Views as a Rules View Loop ? or could you advice how to debugg ?

Or do you know another way to achieve my goal ? (pick a user from ldap then programmatically create the drupal account ?)

my need is exactly what is described here : https://drupal.asu.edu/resources/docs/modules/asu_userpicker . But the module is not available at this url and is designed to be used with other tools.

Thanks

Comment: Edited the title

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by another way :

Within Rules :
First action : create a new entity (user) set the account name, set the account email with a fake value in the email.
**Second action : unblock user** (if blocked, the user account will not be synchronized from LDAP)

Then , when the account is created, the Drupal account is automatically synchronized from LDAP and get the good email.

(In LDAP configuration , be sure to configre LDAP User / BASIC PROVISIONING TO DRUPAL ACCOUNT SETTINGS/ Drupal Account Provisioning Events to  "**Create or Synch to Drupal user anytime a Drupal user account is created or updated.**"